# MS 365 Apps Update 14931.20494 causing EXCEL to crash when trying to access SharePoint via SQL call to .accdb file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Would GREATLY appreciate help on this issue.

I was recently forced to install "Microsoft 365 Apps Update - Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel (Preview) Quality Update for x86 based Edition Version 2202 (Build 14931.20494).  When I did, VBA program button code (on a form) that I wrote that allows user to get data from SharePoint causes EXCEL to crash no matter how I try to trap or ignore errors.  As soon as the "End Sub" line of button code is executed, up comes a "Microsoft EXCEL has stopped working /  Restart the program" window and EXCEL crashes when I click it.  Interesting this is that the data IS returned from SharePoint and displayed on another form just fine.  To get the SharePoint data, I have an Access file (.accdb) set up that defines the SharePoint list.  Below are the pertinent pieces of code:

Const SQLENGSHAREPOINTCONNECTION = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\MORGAN\MACROS\ENG_SHAREPOINT_db.accdb"

** SETUP stuff **

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim StrSql As String

StrSql = "SELECT A.[Material], A.[Status], D.[Name], B.[Name], C.[Name], A.[Priority], A.[ID], A.[Date Requested]," & _
    " A.[Brief ECRDescription], A.[Date Started], A.[Where In Process], A.[Priority]" & _
    " from (([Engineering Change Requests (ECRs)] A" & _
    " Left Join [UserInfo] B On  A.[Product Owner] = B.[ID])" & _
    " Left Join [UserInfo] C On  A.[Principle Engineer] = C.[ID])" & _
    " Left Join [UserInfo] D On  A.[AssignedTo] = D.[ID]" & _
    " where A.[Material] like '%" & myCollection(1) & "%'" & _
    " and Left(A.[Status],2)< 25 "
```

** OPEN CONNECTION stuff **

```
cn.Open SQLENGSHAREPOINTCONNECTION
Set rs = cn.Execute(StrSql)
```

** PROCESSING stuff **

```
If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If rs.Fields(0) <> "" Then
            theDisplay = Left("Material: " & rs![Material] & vbcrlf & theDisplay
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

** CLOSE CONNECTION stuff **

```
If Not (rs Is Nothing) Then
    If (rs.State = 1) Then
        rs.Close
    End If
    Set rs = Nothing
End If
cn.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the update package I installed was a "preview" and sent out to a small number of users for review.  The actual update package that will officially go out does not have this issue.  So the issue turns out to not be an issue.  Both packages did not mention any changes to EXCEL which is odd.